# Video Streaming in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, streaming, media

I just got Windows 7 up and running, and I turned on the new media streaming feature and added all of my music and videos to the corresponding libraries on my machine.  I can then go to my XBox 360 and pull up my entire music collection with no problem, but when I try to find the videos it says there are none.  Now, I DID NOT import any of the music or videos into Windows Media Player...I know you used to have to stream things this way.  But why does it work with Music and not with Videos??  They are all in formats that I know both Windows 7 and the Xbox can play as well...I used to use TVersity and didn't have to even transcode the files to play them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to tell WMP to allow the Xbox to stream. If you go to WMP and the Streaming options, it will pick up your Xbox on the network. Make sure you 'Allow' it. Also, you may or may not have to import to your library. But start with 'Allow' first.

Answer (score 2):

**Network and Shraing Centre>Media Sharing**

Is video sharing enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Music and Video